# How to delete line with echo?

Tags: command-line, echo

I know that I could delete the last three chars with:

```
echo -ne '\b\b\b'
```

But how can I delete a full line? I mean I don't want to use:

```
echo -ne '\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b'
```

...etc... to delete a long line.

Comment: For those who'd like to continuously write on the same line: `echo -ne "\033[2K" ; printf "\r"`, now the line is good as new, as if it was never written to before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just use `echo -ne "\e[2K\r"`. But ANSI escape sequences FTW, nonetheless.

Comment: Also see [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `\b` or `\r` to move the *cursor* back and then overwrite the printed character with a new character.

Note that neither `\b` nor `\r` deletes the printed characters. It just moves the cursor back. `\b` moves the cursor back one character and `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Example:

```
echo -e 'fooooo\b\b\b\bbar
```

will print

```
fobaro
```

while

```
echo -e 'fooooo\rbar'
```

will print:

```
barooo
```

If you want the previous characters "deleted" then you can use the following workaround:

```
echo -e 'fooooo\r      \rbar'
```

or

```
echo -e 'fooooo\rbar   '
```

(note the spaces after bar)

output:

```
bar
```

note that there are now spaces after bar.

output with spaces highlighted

```
bar
   ^^^ spaces
```

for most use cases this will not matter. but if you, for example, modify background color you will notice the spaces.

---

Excerpt from `man echo`:

```
   If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:

   \0NNN  the character whose ASCII code is NNN (octal)

   \\     backslash

   \a     alert (BEL)

   \b     backspace

   \c     produce no further output

   \f     form feed

   \n     new line

   \r     carriage return

   \t     horizontal tab

   \v     vertical tab

   NOTE: your shell may have its own version of echo, which usually super‐
   sedes the version described here.  Please refer to your  shell's  docu‐
   mentation for details about the options it supports.
```

Comment: Yes, but `echo -e 'fooooooooo\rbar` echoes barooooooo.

Comment: Yes you are right. Note that `echo -e 'foooo\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bbar'` also echoes `baroo`.

Comment: So sweet, works even flawlessly in `printf`.

Comment: Very unaccurate answer. Kevin's one is really better

Comment: You're not answering the OP's question. Kevin's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 160):

You're looking for [terminal escapes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).  In particular, to clear from the cursor position to the beginning of the line:

```
echo -e "\033[1K"
```

Or everything on the line, regardless of cursor position:

```
echo -e "\033[2K"
```

And you can do all sorts of other neat tricks with terminal escapes too.

Comment: This assumes a VT100-compatible terminal or emulator (which is a pretty safe assumption these days).

Comment: If you want to erase something you just echoed, your previous echo must have the -n flag, or you'll be sent to a new line

Comment: If you want to write something else, on the line you're erasing, add a -n flag on the echo above, or else you'll go to a new line right after deleting it. Also, append a \r to the string above, or your new content won't go to the beginning of that line.

Comment: -1 | `-e` as `echo` argument is not POSIX compliant + I don't like the escape sequences. Either prefer `printf` or `tput`.

Comment: @Vlastimil why would you downvote this? OP didn't ask for an answer that you would like. Maybe he should have precised that `-e` parameter for `echo` is not POSIX compliant but still...

Comment: `echo -ne "\033[2K\rFoobar"`

Comment: Another useful one is `echo -e "\033[0K"` which clears from the cursor to the end of the line.

Answer (score 39):

If you want to clear the line, then I suggest you use a combination of the carriage return people are mentioning and terminfo.

```
# terminfo clr_eol
ceol=$(tput el)
echo -ne "xyzzyxyzzy\r${ceol}foobar"
```

This will write `xyzzyxyzzy`, then return to the beginning of the line and send the "clear to end of line" sequence to the terminal, then write `foobar`. The `-n` makes echo not add a newline after the `foobar`.

Comment: I like the sort of future-proofing part of this specific solution - using tput possibly means that it'll work on any kind of terminal.

Comment: Better as `printf '%s\r%s%s' xyzzyxyzzy "$ceol" foobar` for portability and to avoid having the content of `$ceol` going through `\x` expansion.

Comment: Best answer if only because it works with arbitrarily long lines. Thanks!

Comment: work perfect. But if i resize terminal screen smaller than output line, it becomes messy.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example using echo's *no newline* `-n` and *carriage return* `\r` options.

[image: bash overwrite terminal line]

```
#!/bin/bash

CHECK_MARK="\033[0;32m\xE2\x9C\x94\033[0m"

echo -e "\n\e[4mDoing Things\e[0m"
echo -n "doing thing 1..."
sleep 1
echo -e "\\r${CHECK_MARK} thing 1 done"
```

Comment: Check mark works even on RHEL6. Nice for purely aesthetical edits of my scripts

Answer (score 12):

You explicitly ask for `echo`, but this request pins you down. Here's an approach that uses bash's builtin `printf` command with brace expansion:

```
printf 'fooooooooo' # 10 characters
printf '\r'; printf ' %0.s' {0..9} # 10 expansions of the space character
```

Comment: perfect! exactly what I needed

Comment: printf 'Status: started';sleep 2s;printf '\r';printf 'Status: updated';sleep 2s;printf '\r';

Answer (score 2):

Here is a countdown timer example I use:

```
i=10
while [ $i -gt 0 ]; 
do 
  printf "$i seconds remaining       " && printf '\r\033[1B'
  i=`expr $i - 1`
  sleep 1
  printf '\033[1A'
done
```

Comment: -1 | Maybe you wanted to intentionally make a one-liner, but that's actually only good for testing. I would re-write it properly with new lines.

Comment: Then, go ahead and do it and add a new answer. Or propose an edit of my answer.

Comment: Perfect, this was what I was looking for for my script to print a running total

Comment: If you want to do it with multiple lines, use `tput cuu 2`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `echo -en "\r"` you might also find the `printf "\r"` command as useful. This way you can format the string. e.g.:

```
for sec in {1..100}; do printf "\r %04d" ${sec}; sleep 0.1; done
```

I usually do that as well when operating with slow file parsing to display the filename currently in progress without creating a list

Comment: -1 | Maybe you wanted to intentionally make a one-liner, but that's actually only good for testing. I would re-write it properly with new lines.

Answer (score 0):

As question is delete the full line

I have used below command with combination of `echo` and `sed` to delete line

After execution of command result will be empty.since while line will be replaced with none

command

```
echo  "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b" | sed -r "s/.*//g"
```