# Why is printf better than echo?

Tags: text-processing, echo, printf

I have heard that `printf` is better than `echo`. I can recall only one instance from my experience where I had to use `printf` because `echo` didn't work for feeding some text into some program on RHEL 5.8 but `printf` did.  But apparently, there are other differences, and I would like to inquire what they are as well as if there are specific cases when to use one vs the other.

Comment: I've added a big and very-related answer here ([Stack Overflow: Piping echo to netcat fails while piping printf passes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001189/piping-echo-to-netcat-fails-while-piping-printf-passes/70001270#70001270)) which quotes from and references the main answer below.

Answer (score 983, accepted):

Basically, it's a portability (and reliability) issue.

Initially, `echo` didn't accept any option and didn't expand anything. All it was doing was outputting its arguments separated by a space character and terminated by a newline character.

Now, someone thought it would be nice if we could do things like `echo "\n\t"` to output newline or tab characters, or have an option not to output the trailing newline character.

They then thought harder but instead of adding that functionality to the shell (like `perl` where inside double quotes, `\t` actually means a tab character), they added it to `echo`.

David Korn realized the mistake and introduced a new form of shell quotes: `$'...'` which was later copied by `bash` and `zsh` but it was far too late by that time.

Now when a standard UNIX `echo` receives an argument which contains the two characters `\` and `t`, instead of outputting them, it outputs a tab character. And as soon as it sees `\c` in an argument, it stops outputting (so the trailing newline is not output either).

Other shells/Unix vendors/versions chose to do it differently: they added a `-e` option to expand escape sequences, and a `-n` option to not output the trailing newline. Some have a `-E` to disable escape sequences, some have `-n` but not `-e`, and the list of escape sequences supported by one `echo` implementation is not necessarily the same as that supported by another.

Sven Mascheck has a [nice page that shows the extent of the problem](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/echo+printf/).

On those `echo` implementations that support options, there's generally no support of a `--` to mark the end of options (the `echo` builtin of some non-Bourne-like shells and toybox `echo` (Android's standalone `echo` utility) do, and zsh supports `-` for that though), so for instance, it's difficult to output `"-n"` with `echo` in many shells.

On some shells like `bash`¹ or `ksh93`² or `yash` (`$ECHO_STYLE` variable), the behaviour even depends on how the shell was compiled or the environment (GNU `echo`'s behaviour will also change if `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment and with the version<sup>4</sup>, `zsh`'s with its `bsd_echo` option, some pdksh-based with their `posix` option or whether they're called as `sh` or not). So two `bash` `echo`s, even from the same version of `bash` are not guaranteed to behave the same.

POSIX says: *if the first argument is `-n` or any argument contains backslashes, then the behaviour is unspecified*. `bash` echo in that regard is not POSIX in that for instance `echo -e` is not outputting `-e<newline>` as POSIX requires. The UNIX specification is stricter, it prohibits `-n` and requires the expansion of some escape sequences including the `\c` one to stop outputting.

Those specifications don't really come to the rescue here given that many implementations are not compliant. Even some *certified* systems like macOS<sup>5</sup> are not compliant.

To really represent the current reality, [POSIX should actually say](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1222): *if the first argument matches the `^-([eEn]*|-|-help|-version)$` extended regexp or any argument contains backslashes (or characters whose encoding contains the encoding of the backslash character like `α` in locales using the BIG5 charset), then the behaviour is unspecified.*

All in all, you don't know what `echo "$var"` will output unless you can make sure that `$var` doesn't contain backslash characters and doesn't start with `-`. The POSIX specification actually does tell us to use `printf` instead in that case.

**So what that means is that you can't use `echo` to display uncontrolled data. In other words, if you're writing a script and it is taking external input (from the user as arguments, or file names from the file system...), you can't use `echo` to display it.**

This is OK:

```sh
echo >&2 Invalid file.
```

This is not:

```sh
echo >&2 "Invalid file: $file"
```

(Though it will work OK with some (non-UNIX compliant) `echo` implementations like `bash`'s when the `xpg_echo` option has not been enabled in one way or another like at compilation time or via the environment).

`file=$(echo "$var" | tr ' ' _)` is not OK in most implementations (exceptions being `yash` with `ECHO_STYLE=raw` (with the caveat that `yash`'s variables can't hold arbitrary sequences of bytes so not arbitrary file names) and `zsh`'s `echo -E - "$var"`<sup>6</sup>).

`printf`, on the other hand, is more reliable, at least when it's limited to the basic usage of `echo`.

```sh
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

Will output the content of `$var` followed by a newline character regardless of what character it may contain.

```sh
printf '%s' "$var"
```

Will output it without the trailing newline character.

Now, there also are differences between `printf` implementations. There's a core of features that is specified by POSIX, but then there are a lot of extensions. For instance, some support a `%q` to quote the arguments but how it's done varies from shell to shell, some support `\uxxxx` for Unicode characters. The behaviour varies for `printf '%10s\n' "$var"` in multi-byte locales, there are at least three different outcomes for `printf %b '\123'`

But in the end, if you stick to the POSIX feature set of `printf` and don't try doing anything too fancy with it, you're out of trouble.

But remember the first argument is the format, so shouldn't contain variable/uncontrolled data.

A more reliable `echo` can be implemented using `printf`, like:

```sh
echo() ( # subshell for local scope for $IFS
  IFS=" " # needed for "$*"
  printf '%s\n' "$*"
)

echo_n() (
  IFS=" "
  printf %s "$*"
)

echo_e() (
  IFS=" "
  printf '%b\n' "$*"
)
```

The subshell (which implies spawning an extra process in most shell implementations) can be avoided using `local IFS` with many shells, or by writing it like this:

```sh
echo() {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
     printf %s "$1"
     shift
     if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
       printf ' %s' "$@"
     fi
  fi
  printf '\n'
}
```

In ksh88 and pdksh and some of its derivatives, `printf` is not built-in. There, you may prefer using `print -r --` (for `echo`) and `print -rn --` (for `echo -n`/`\c`) which print their arguments space-separated (and followed by a newline without `-n`) without alteration (also works in `zsh`).

---

### Notes

#### 1. how `bash`'s `echo` behaviour can be altered.

With `bash`, at run time, there are two things that control the behaviour of `echo` (beside `enable -n echo` or redefining `echo` as a function or alias):
the `xpg_echo` `bash` option and whether `bash` is in posix mode. `posix` mode can be enabled if `bash` is called as `sh` or if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment or with the the `posix` option:

The default behaviour on most systems:

```sh
$ bash -c 'echo -n "\0101"'
\0101% # the % here denotes the absence of newline character
```

`xpg_echo` expands sequences as UNIX requires:

```sh
$ BASHOPTS=xpg_echo bash -c 'echo "\0101"'
A
```

It still honours `-n` and `-e` (and `-E`):

```sh
$ BASHOPTS=xpg_echo bash -c 'echo -n "\0101"'
A%
```

With `xpg_echo` and POSIX mode:

```sh
$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash -c 'echo -n "\0101"'
-n A
$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo sh -c 'echo -n "\0101"' # (where sh is a symlink to bash)
-n A
$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo SHELLOPTS=posix bash -c 'echo -n "\0101"'
-n A
```

This time, `bash` is both POSIX and UNIX conformant. Note that in POSIX mode, `bash` is still not POSIX conformant as it doesn't output `-e` in:

```sh
$ env SHELLOPTS=posix bash -c 'echo -e'

$
```

The default values for xpg_echo and posix can be defined at compilation time with the `--enable-xpg-echo-default` and `--enable-strict-posix-default` options to the `configure` script. That's typically what recent versions of OS/X do to build their `/bin/sh`. <strike>No Unix/Linux implementation/distribution in their right mind would typically do that for `/bin/bash` though</strike>. Actually, that's not true, the `/bin/bash` that Oracle ships with Solaris 11 (in an optional package) seems to be built with `--enable-xpg-echo-default` (that was not the case in Solaris 10).

#### 2. How `ksh93`'s `echo` behaviour can be altered

In `ksh93`, whether `echo` expands escape sequences or not and recognises options depends on the content of the `$PATH` and/or `$_AST_FEATURES` environment variables.

If `$PATH` contains a component that contains `/5bin` or `/xpg` before the `/bin` or `/usr/bin` component then it behave the SysV/UNIX way (expands sequences, doesn't accept options). If it finds `/ucb` or `/bsd` first or if `$_AST_FEATURES`<sup>7</sup> contains `UNIVERSE = ucb`, then it behaves the BSD<sup>3</sup> way (`-e` to enable expansion, recognises `-n`).

The default is system dependent, BSD on Debian (see the output of `builtin getconf; getconf UNIVERSE` in recent versions of ksh93):

```sh
$ ksh93 -c 'echo -n' # default -> BSD (on Debian)
$ PATH=/foo/xpgbar:$PATH ksh93 -c 'echo -n' # /xpg before /bin or /usr/bin -> XPG
-n
$ PATH=/5binary:$PATH ksh93 -c 'echo -n' # /5bin before /bin or /usr/bin -> XPG
-n
$ PATH=/5binary:$PATH _AST_FEATURES='UNIVERSE = ucb' ksh93 -c 'echo -n' # -> BSD
$ PATH=/ucb:/foo/xpgbar:$PATH ksh93 -c 'echo -n' # /ucb first -> BSD
$ PATH=/bin:/foo/xpgbar:$PATH ksh93 -c 'echo -n' # /bin before /xpg -> default -> BSD
```

### 3. BSD for echo -e?

The reference to BSD for the handling of the `-e` option is a bit misleading here. Most of those different and incompatible `echo` behaviours were all introduced at AT&T:

- `\n`, `\0ooo`, `\c` in Programmer's Work Bench UNIX (based on Unix V6), and the rest (`\b`, `\r`...) in Unix System III<sup>[Ref](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/echo+printf/)</sup>.
- `-n` in Unix V7 (by Dennis Ritchie<sup>[Ref](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoug/reader.pdf)</sup>)
- `-e` in Unix V8 (by Dennis Ritchie<sup>[Ref](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoug/reader.pdf)</sup>)
- `-E` itself possibly initially came from `bash` (CWRU/CWRU.chlog in [version 1.13.5](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/gnu/bash/bash-1.13.5.tar.gz) mentions Brian Fox adding it on 1992-10-18, GNU `echo` copying it shortly after in sh-utils-1.8 released 10 days later)

While the `echo` builtin of the `sh` of BSD has supported `-e` since the day they started using the Almquist shell for it in the early 90s, the standalone `echo` utility to this day doesn't support it there ([FreeBSD `echo`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=echo&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.0-stable&arch=default&format=html) still doesn't support `-e`, though it does support `-n` like Unix V7 (and also `\c` but only at the end of the last argument)).

The handling of `-e` was added to `ksh93`'s `echo` when in the BSD *universe* in the ksh93r version released in 2006 and can be disabled at compilation time.

### 4. GNU echo change of behaviour in 8.31

Since coreutils 8.31 (and [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/echo.c?id=8d328706c6ef0264dffb923f96431af1e26dcddd)), GNU `echo` now expands escape sequences by default when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment, to match the behaviour of `bash -o posix -O xpg_echo`'s `echo` builtin (see [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=32703)).

### 5. macOS `echo`

Most versions of macOS have [received UNIX certification from the OpenGroup](/a/1490).

Their `sh` builtin `echo` is compliant as it's `bash` (a very old version) built with `xpg_echo` enabled by default, but their stand-alone `echo` utility is not. `env echo -n` outputs nothing instead of `-n<newline>`, `env echo '\n'` outputs `\n<newline>` instead of `<newline><newline>`.

That `/bin/echo` is the one from FreeBSD which suppresses newline output if the first argument is `-n` or (since 1995) if the last argument ends in `\c`, but doesn't support any other backslash sequences required by UNIX, not even `\\`.

### 6. `echo` implementations that can output arbitrary data verbatim

Strictly speaking, you could also count that FreeBSD/macOS `/bin/echo` above (not their shell's `echo` builtin) where `zsh`'s `echo -E - "$var"` or `yash`'s `ECHO_STYLE=raw echo "$var"` (`printf '%s\n' "$var"`) could be written:

```sh
/bin/echo "$var
\c"
```

And `zsh`'s `echo -nE - "$var"` (`printf %s "$var"`) could be written

```sh
/bin/echo "$var\c"
```

Implementations that support `-E` and `-n` (or can be configured to) can also do:

```sh
echo -nE "$var
"
```

For the equivalent of `printf '%s\n' "$var"`.

### 7. `_AST_FEATURES` and the AST `UNIVERSE`

The `_AST_FEATURES` is not meant to be manipulated directly, it is used to propagate AST configuration settings across command execution. The configuration is meant to be done via the (undocumented) `astgetconf()` API. Inside `ksh93`, the `getconf` builtin (enabled with `builtin getconf` or by invoking `command /opt/ast/bin/getconf`) is the interface to `astgetconf()`

For instance, you'd do `builtin getconf; getconf UNIVERSE = att` to change the `UNIVERSE` setting to `att` (causing `echo` to behave the SysV way among other things). After doing that, you'll notice the `$_AST_FEATURES` environment variable contains `UNIVERSE = att`.

Comment: A lot of early unix development happened in isolation, and good software engineering principles like  *'when you change the interface, change the name'* were not applied.

Comment: As a note, the one (and maybe only) advantage of having `echo` expand the `\x` sequences as opposed to the shell as part of the quoting syntax is that you can then output a NUL byte (another arguably mis-design of Unix is those null-delimited strings, where half the system calls (like `execve()`) can't take arbitrary sequences of bytes)

Comment: I'm amazed at how much you know about echo and printf!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Is there a reason why you would avoid using the word `local` in your "plain echo" function? Wouldn't it better be `echo() { local IFS=" " ; printf '%s\n' "$*" ;}` without the subshell?

Comment: @Pourko, I do mention `local IFS` for the shells that support it. `local` is not a standard command though.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation of `echo` and `printf` ! @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: `so for instance, it's difficult to output "-n" with echo in many shells`. +1 on that! On bash on Ubuntu 18.04. `echo "-n"` should output `-n`. Instead, it outputs nothing since it accepts that as the same thing as the `-n` flag. `echo -- "-n"` should solve that and output `-n`, but it doesn't. It outputs `-- -n` instead. I see your point very well now. `printf` is better.

Comment: I got stuck on the `echo` vs `printf` problem too, here: [Cmd `echo`ed to `netcat` fails while cmd `printf`ed to `netcat` passes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70001189/4561887)

Comment: @Pourko because `local variable` is not POSIX-shell and in POSIX-shell there is no local scope, so variables in functions are global. Eventually you would be able to save `IFS` and avoid most name collisions with: `echo () { __echo_OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=' '; printf '%s\n' "$*"; IFS="$__echo_OIFS";}`

Comment: @GabrielStaples, it's completely correct for `echo -n` and `echo "-n"` to have identical behavior. Quotes are applied and discarded at parsing phase, before a command is called at all. Behaviors implemented as shell syntax can inspect which individual characters were quoted at all, but regular commands and even built-ins just get an argument vector pre-parsed into an array of C strings. Thus, if anyone built a shell with an `echo` that _could_ distinguish between `echo -n` and `echo "-n"`, that behavior would necessarily be different from that of `/usr/bin/echo`, which just receives an array.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, note that in the rc shell or derivatives like es or akanga, `"..."` are not a quoting operator, `echo "-n"` actually outputs `"-n"<newline>` there (including the quotes). Bourne-like, csh-like and fish at least do have `"..."` as a quoting operator so `echo -n` is the same as `echo "-n"` (except in locales where `-` or `n` are classified as *blank* with some shells, but that would be broken/rogue locales...)

Answer (score 35):

You might want to use `printf` for its formatting options. `echo` is useful when it comes to printing the value of a variable or a (simple) line, but that's all there is to it. `printf` can basically do what the C version of it can do.

Example usage and capabilities:

## `Echo`:

```
echo "*** Backup shell script ***"
echo
echo "Runtime: $(date) @ $(hostname)"
echo
```

## `printf`:

```
vech="bike"
printf "%s\n" "$vech"
```

Sources:

- http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Echo_Command
- [man echo](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?echo)
- [man printf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf)

Comment: Using `echo` to print a variable can fail if the value of the variable contains meta-characters.

Comment: I'd include this printf exemple:  `printf "*** Backup shell script ***\n\nRuntime: %s @ %s\n\n" "$(date)" "$(hostname)"`  # ie, the same display as the echo line above

Answer (score 20):

One "advantage", if you want to call it that, would be that you don't have to tell it like `echo` to interpret certain escape sequences such as `\n`. It knows to interpret them and won't require an `-e` to do so.

```
printf "some\nmulti-lined\ntext\n"
```

(NB: the last `\n` is necessary, `echo` implies it, unless you give the `-n` option)

versus

```
echo -e "some\nmulti-lined\ntext"
```

Note the last `\n` in `printf`. At the end of the day it's a matter of taste and *requirements* what you use: [`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) or [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf).

Comment: True for `/usr/bin/echo` and the `bash` builtin. The `dash`, `ksh` and `zsh` builtin `echo` does not need `-e` switch to expand backslash-escaped characters.

Comment: Why the scare quotes? Your wording implies that it isn't necessarily a real advantage.

Comment: @KeithThompson: actually all they are *meant* to imply is that not everyone may consider it an advantage.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Why wouldn't it be an advantage? The phrase "if you want to call it that" implies pretty strongly that you think it isn't.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I can think of a few scenarios where you'd like to preserve the escape characters to pass them on (e.g. store them in a file). In this case `echo` is more flexible in a sense, since you can suppress the processing of escape characters. To me, yes indeed, it's a slim advantage. And I would hardly call it that but the OP decided to call it that, so I went with the OP's wording. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a stupid issue that should be taken care of in the language, not in the utilities. The shell language shuld provide way of entering string literals in which escapes are recognized at lexical analysis time, so you can easily pass such strings to any command.  Handling this in `printf` is a bad design because it means that if `$STRING` contains an escape sequence like `\n` (the actual two characters, and not the newline character) then `printf $STRING` will interpret it, causing a newline to be output even though printf doesn't contain such a thing.

Comment: @Kaz: agreed. And that's where it's not an advantage ;) ... so you end up using `echo` (without `-e`) again. But then, escaping rules hold for all strings.

Comment: Or you could just do `printf '%s\n' 'foo\bar`.

Comment: It's only a questionable "advantage" if you're putting data in the format string position. That's always wrong. `printf '%s\n' "$data"` keeps your data safely out-of-band and is how the POSIX specification advises that printf be used; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html describing how to correctly use printf instead.

Answer (score 5):

One downside of `printf` is performance because the built-in shell `echo` is much faster. This comes into play particularly in Cygwin where each instance of a new command causes heavy Windows overhead. When I changed my echo-heavy program from using `/bin/echo` to the shell's echo the performance almost doubled. It's a trade off between portability and performance. It's not a slam dunk to always use `printf`.

Comment: `printf` is built in most shells nowadays (bash, dash, ksh, zsh, yash, some pdksh derivatives... so includes the shells typically found on cygwin as well). The only notable exceptions are some `pdksh` derivatives.

Comment: But many of those printf implementations are broken. This is essential when you like to use `printf` to output nul bytes, but some implementations interpret `\c' in the format string even though they should not.

Comment: @schily, the behaviour of `printf` is unspecified by POSIX if you use `\c` in the format string, so `printf` implementations can do whatever they  want in that regard. For instance, some treat it the same as in the PWB `echo` (causes printf to exit), ksh uses it for `\cA` control characters (for the printf format argument and for `$'...'` but not for `echo` nor `print`!). Not sure what that has to do with printing NUL bytes, or maybe you're refering to `ksh`'s `printf '\c@'`?